# How to remove vuetify v-slider-group arrows on mobile and desktop

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I would like to remove the arrows on the v-slider-group on both mobile and desktop. There is a prop for show-arrows which will disable arrows on mobile however it does not seem to help on desktop. My code is below:

```
<template>
        <v-container>
            <v-row>
                <v-col cols="6" class="pa-10">
                    <v-row>
                        <v-carousel v-model="imgModel" :show-arrows="false" hide-delimiters class="rounded-lg mb-5">
                            <v-carousel-item v-for="(item,index) in data" :key="index"
                                :src="item['src']"
                                aspect-ratio = "1" cover>
                            </v-carousel-item>
                        </v-carousel>
                    </v-row>
                    <v-row>
                        <v-slide-group
                        v-model="imgModel"
                        center-active
                        mandatory
                        :show-arrows = "false"
                        >
                            <v-slide-group-item
                                v-for="(item,n) in data"
                                :key="n"
                                v-slot="{ isSelected, toggle }"
                            >
                                <v-img width="100" cover class="rounded-lg mx-1" :src="item.src" @click="toggle() ; updateImg(item);"></v-img>
                            </v-slide-group-item>
                        </v-slide-group>
                    </v-row>
                </v-col>
                <v-col cols="6" class="pa-10">
                    
                </v-col>
            </v-row>
        </v-container>
</template>
```

Is my only option to adde a style tag and display:none somewhere? I tried :

```
.v-slide-group__next, .v-slide-group__prev {
    display: none !important;
}
```

but nothing?

Comment: just remove the prop `:show-arrows = "false"`

Comment: you don't mention if your styling is scoped or not.  if it is, it won't affect the styling of elements internal to other components (e.g. v-slider-group__next).  you need to either not scope the style or use [deep](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#deep-selectors) selector